# How to reduce resonance from livingroom table

Tags: acoustics

[image]

Odd ting, the table surface echo/resonance sound when speaking, especially lower lower frequencies. It helped putting on a cloth, but it did not completely remove resonance. Putting a rug beneath did not affect. Wonder whether box for roof lights may act as sound box or if it is just room size and large surfaces that are the cause? Also, would putting sound absorbing mat on wall or roof help?
Greatful for all answers.

Comment: Just to be clear, you are saying that your table vibrates when you speak?

Comment: I doubt it's the table or the roof box resonating. More likely, it is a standing wave in the air between those two parallel hard surfaces. A thin cloth on the table won't do much - try covering the table with a duvet from your bed, as an experiment. To get rid of the resonance you probably need a false ceiling with  sound-absorber layer behind it.

Comment: Move the table a couple feet to verify it's the table and not the walls and tray ceiling at that location.    And yes, one of the first approaches to take to dampen sound is absorbing panels on the ceiling. May be ugly, though

Comment: In line with what @alephzero wrote you could try hanging mobiles &/or a low long light fitting over the table to break up any standing wave. This will probably spoil the aesthetics & ambience. You could experiment by rigging a temporary system of pole with string/cable attached & hanging things from the cables.

Comment: Difficult to feel if the table vibrates, but clear echo/sound from table surface can be heard. When holding a plast tray with diameter 40 cm approx 50 cm above center of table, it vibrates. Will try a horisontal string too, soon. Thanks for all comments, I am newbie, but will try to give cred accordingly.

Comment: Find solution and then make it work.  You have to change dynamics.  Rotate table 45° or 90°.  Add heavy fruit bowl.  Place screen before Table.  Could be sound bouncing off large window, so full curtain - try a bedsheet.  Exorcism??   Put a full table cloth on.  Put something under objects on Table.  Chairs with metal legs, does not help.  Move chairs and see if problem persists.

Comment: Does an empty ceramic dish vibrate too? If so you need a heavier table cloth to damp the vibration. Next, did you try to cover the window with the curtain made of heavy cloth?

Comment: I would try a thicker cloth or a rubber pad as a damper/obsorber. What you heard/feel is the sound wave reflecting from the table surface.

Answer (score 0):

acoustic resonance is not uncommon in small rooms without acoustic damping. as a rule of thumb: to have an audible damping effect, you will need to entirely cover *one whole wall* with damping material. this is most easily done by putting in a carpet that covers the whole floor of the room.

Answer (score 0):

This is meant more as a comment but my reputation is too low.

There are many ways to address this.  Your description seems more like a flutter echo than a true resonance, so try hanging something round over the table --a diffuser.  Maybe a basket ball or a beach ball just too see if it works.  If it does, then anything "complicated" like a chandelier or a ceiling fan will knock that right out.

There are lots of complicated things you can do; Google "architectural clouds" for entertainment :-)

Comment: cool, will try a string.. as commented above, a plastic tray above the table could be felt vibrating...

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is not because of the table. You can check this out by moving the table to another location in the room and talking again at the former table location.

While mid and high frequencies will be easily absorbed by carpets ([ref](https://soundproofcentral.com/does-carpet-absorb-sound/)), you may need to break up the room symmetry to remove low-frequency resonances: add shelve units (and fill them), and large objects in the corners ("club" chairs...) ([ref](https://www.wikihow.com/Acoustically-Tune-a-Room)).